# @ionic-native/network value capture from observable

Tags: angular, ionic2, observable

I am using the @ionic-native/network with the cordova-plugin-network-information plugin for checking online-offline status. However i'm having difficulty updating the network status.

**home.ts**

```
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
public online:boolean=false;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private network: Network) {
      this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
         this.online=false;
         console.log(this.online);      });
      this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
          this.online=true;
        console.log(this.online);
      });
  }

}
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h1>{{online}}</h1>
</ion-content>
```

However on running the application, it only shows false, yet the `console.log(this.online)` shows true-false changes whenever i toggle the wifi. Any suggestions on how to make the interface values to changes as well.
[image: Chrome Inspect output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try and use [**ChangeDetectorRef**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html), if change detection for some reason isn't happening in template:

```ts
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
     this.online = false;
     console.log(this.online);  
     this.ref.detectChanges(); // run    
  });
  this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
      this.online=true;
      console.log(this.online);
      this.ref.detectChanges(); // run
  });
}
```

Comment: Great! Happy to hear that! :)

Comment: @AJT_82 great :)

Answer (score 2):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
public online:boolean=false;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private network: Network) {}

  ngOnInit(){
      this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
         this.online=true;
         console.log(this.online);

         this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
          this.online=false;
          console.log(this.online);
         });

     });

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the repy but still the interface value doesn't change yet the console.log shows changing network status